# The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation (CosmosDb)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm encountering an issue with LINQ in Azure Cosmos DB, specifically a 'System.InvalidOperationException.' Notably, my LINQ queries work fine with EF Core In-Memory DB in tests but throw this error with Cosmos DB. Have there been any known challenges or differences when using LINQ with Cosmos DB?

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Media>()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)
     at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

and here is my code

```
var messages =await _context.Messages
    .Where(x => x.RoomChatId == roomId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
    .Select(message =>
        new MessageResponse
        {
            id = message.id,
            CreatedDate = message.CreatedDate,
            MediaList = message.MediaList!.Select(x => new MediaResponse
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Type = (MediaTypeResponse)x.Type,
                BlurHash = x.BlurHash,
                Path = x.Path
            }).ToList(),

            Text = message.Text,
            GroupInviteToken = message.GroupInvitationToken,
            ModifiedDate = message.ModifiedDate,
            ReplyMessageId = message.ReplyMessageId,
            UserSender = _context.Users.Where(x => x.id == message.UserSenderId).Select(x => new PreviewUserResponse()
            {
                Id = x.id,
                Name = x.FullName,
                ProfileImage = FileStorageHelper.GetUrl(x.ProfileImage)
            }).Single()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

and this is my message Entity and Media is inside message and it's not apart entity

```
public class Message : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid RoomChatId { get; set; }

    public string? Text { get; set; }

    public Guid UserSenderId { get; set; }

    public string? GroupInvitationToken { get; set; }

    public Guid? ReplyMessageId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Media>? MediaList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this the full expression text? Can you please add type definitions (for `Message`, `MediaList`, etc.)

Comment: @regestea23 could you try accessing Users using the mapped relationships instead of _context.Users ?

Comment: I think you should try simplified its, remove sub query and try figure out which part is the problem. I guess it's on the sub query part. Or you can change to use mongo driver instead. its should be work.

Comment: The `'DbSet<Media>()' could not be translated.` is quite strange in the error. I can't see where it comes from based on the provided code. Do you have a [mre]?

Comment: i didn't DbSet<Media>() because it's document non-relational database , the Media is Collection inside Message Entity